# Ruby module method not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a Rubygem which contains the following:

```
module BoardGameGem
    API_ROOT = "https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi2"
    MAX_ATTEMPTS = 10

    def BoardGameGem.get_item(id, statistics = false, options = {})
        options[:id] = id
        options[:stats] = statistics ? 1 : 0
        item = BGGItem.new(BoardGameGem.request_xml("thing", options))
        return item.id == 0 ? nil : item
    end

    def BoardGameGem.get_items(ids, statistics = false, options = {})
        options[:id] = ids.join(",")
        options[:stats] = statistics ? 1 : 0
        item_xml = BoardGameGem.request_xml("thing", options)
        item_list = []
        item_xml.css("item").wrap("<item_data></item_data>")
        item_xml.css("item_data").each do |item_data|
            item_list.push(BGGItem.new(item_data))
        end
        item_list
    end

    ...
```

When I try to use the gem from my Rails application with `BoardGameGem.get_items(id_list, true)`, I get the response:

```
undefined method `get_items' for BoardGameGem:Module Did you mean? get_item
```

`Gem.loaded_specs["board-game-gem"].version` gives the correct version number, and using `module_function` did not solve the problem either. `BoardGameGem.methods` shows that the method, in fact, doesn't exist. I can't figure out what might be causing the method to not show up.

Comment: How are you using your gem in the driver class (e.g. `require`, `include`)? Are you sure you're uninstalling the old gem, rebuilding and reinstalling after making changes?

Answer (score 3):

I would have thought it would look more like:

```
module BoardGameGem
  API_ROOT = "https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi2"
  MAX_ATTEMPTS = 10

  def self.get_item(id, statistics = false, options = {})
    ...
  end

  def self.get_items(ids, statistics = false, options = {})
    ...
  end
end
```

EDIT:

If I do this in console:

```
module BoardGameGem

  def self.get_item(id, statistics = false, options={})
  end

  def self.get_items(ids, statistics = false, options={})
    puts "ids: #{ids}"
    puts "statistics: #{statistics}"
  end

end
```

And then I do:

```
BoardGameGem.methods.include?(:get_item)
BoardGameGem.methods.include?(:get_items)
BoardGameGem.get_items([1,2], true)
```

I get:

```
irb(main):088:0> BoardGameGem.methods.include?(:get_item)
=> true
irb(main):089:0> BoardGameGem.methods.include?(:get_items)
=> true
irb(main):090:0> BoardGameGem.get_items([1,2], true)
ids: [1, 2]
statistics: true
=> nil
```

Comment: This is the Ruby conventional way of doing it.

Comment: I've changed it to self, but the problem still remains.

Comment: @tadman I would say, “it is a ruby conventional way of doing it”—if the method definition is placed inside `module` definition _and_ there is the only method to declare as module function. Otherwise, `class << self ; def get_item` is more conventional.

Comment: @mudasobwa - Personally, I use the approach you describe (`class << self`) because (a) I got tired of typing `self` all the time, (b) I like the aesthetics better, and (c) IMO it makes code easier to read. I had thought the OP's problem was declaring methods as `def Module.method`. But, turns out that's completely legal, too (which actually makes sense). So, we have three viable ways of declaring methods in modules (at least).

Comment: @jvillian in fact, [`Module#module_function`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Module.html#method-i-module_function) does the same as well, but it has a side effect: the method becomes both defined on both module and instance level, as by `extend self`.

Comment: @mudasobwa - Nice! People like you that make this place AWESOME. Thanks for sharing your knowledge and know-how.

Comment: @mudasobwa I've only seen `class << self` in much older code-bases, it used to be a tradition but it's fading in popularity. It introduces an extra level of indentation and makes finding methods more of an nuisance, `def x` and `def self.x` are much clearer when you're searching.

Comment: @tadman Rails5 [has 119 occurences](https://github.com/rails/rails/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22class+%3C%3C+self%22), with the newest change dated this March :) This is definitely the matter of both habit and guidelines in the team; I don’t see any problem grepping for `"def (self\.)?method"`, but I agree that `self.` looks more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a boardgamegem.rb and a board-game-gem.rb, and I was editing the first without realising it. Not my day it seems...

Comment: It didn't actually change anything, but it's definitely better form, so thanks for that suggestion!